# Logging in as root in MySQL does not require password

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin, debian

Whenever I try to login via SSH on my MySQL server, the 'root' user does not require me to provide a password.

I already tried the suggestion from this [guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html), however, I still have no luck.

```
UPDATE mysql.user
SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('MyPass'), password_expired = 'N'
WHERE User = 'root' AND Host = 'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

and

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyPass';
```

I manage my database using phpMyAdmin and when I checked my user groups, before it says that 'root' doesn't have a password but when I tried the codes above, it changed the password to 'Yes', but still allows me to login as root via ssh.

Another problem is I cannot login using the 'root' user in phpMyAdmin.

By the way, im using MySQL 5.7.21 for Debian9

---

Update 4/10:
Some googling lead me to threads that says later version of MySQL/phpMyAdmin does not allow root to login anymore, but a month ago I was able to do it, unfortunately I forgot the steps that I did..

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if you have a `.my.cnf` file in your home folder or in `/etc/mysql/` ?

It could contain root credentials.

Also can you print the complete contents of your users table? There might be another entry giving root permissions when connecting locally.

Comment: Yes i do have the .my.cnf file on the said directory, unfortunately, they are blank.   
   
  
Here are the list of users on my database:   
   
debian-sys-maint   
mysql.session   
msql.sys   
phpmyadmin  
root

Comment: The users do not matter, but the access they have. That why i asked for a dump of the user table (without the password hashes)

Comment: Oh my bad, are you talking about the global priveleges?